# Angular 2 children root without path in first level

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have these components:

**LoginComponent** /login

**CoreComponent** No own route, only for wrapping other components (not the login, register, etc...)

**HomeComponent** /home
**Entries** /entries

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'x',
    component: CoreComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'entries', component: EntriesComponent },
  ]},
];
```

The route is now /x/home or /x/entries and /login for the login.

How to remove the x from the first level path?

Comment: I don't think you can remove x from the path since its the parent. What you can do is put the home or entries outside the children array of x. Why do you have them as children if you don't want it?

Comment: Removing the `x`  will do. Just use `''` as path.

Comment: I wrap the components because the navigation and so on is placed in the CoreComponent...

Comment: How is that preventing you from removing `x` from `path: 'x'`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have to use `CoreComponent`, you can simplify your routes like that;

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
     {
          path: '',
          redirectTo: 'home',
          pathMatch: 'full'
     },
     {
          path: 'home',
          component: HomeComponent
     },
     ...
]
```

If you have to use `CoreComponent` and there is no other route which uses empty path `''`, you can just remove `x` from parent route. Also, you can take a look at [this](http://vsavkin.tumblr.com/post/146722301646/angular-router-empty-paths-componentless-routes). Please let me know for any further questions.

Comment: I have to use it because I wrap the second router-outlet with a template...

Answer (score 1):

Just write your routes like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home',
    children: [
      { path: 'entries', component: EntriesComponent },
  ]},
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the below code, but give it a go it may work out for you.

```
[
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [CanActivateHomeOrEntries],
    resolve: {
      token: TokenNeededForBothHomeAndEntries
    },

    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'entries',
        component: EntriesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```